# How to keep clients on Magento 1 given that end of life is in 11/2018

Tags: magento2, magento-1, upgrade, openmage

Magento will not release any new security patches from 11/2018 for Magento 1.

Of course, there are a lot of small and not so small websites out there that are on Magento 1 that **can't afford** to move to Magento 2 (especially given the current relatively bigger costs to develop a new Magento 2 site).

From a **developer** point of view, what assurances (regarding security/bug fixes) can we give to current clients to stay on Magento 1 even after 2018 and continue to invest in new features and not switch to a new platform?

From similar experiences on other platforms did the community/hosting companies keep focus on the old version and continued to offer security fixes?

Answer (score 11):

> From a developer point of view, what assurances (regarding
>   security/bug fixes) can we give to current clients to stay on magento1
>   even after 2018 and not switch to a new platform?

Well, **you can't give any assurance regarding security and bug fixes as they won't be anymore releases/patches for M1 from November 2018.**

Also, if by "switching to a new platform" you mean "going from Magento 1 to Shopify (for example)" then, depending on the level of customization of your M1 store, it'll be cheaper to migrate to M2 IMO.

Now, there's 3 different cases from what I've heard from the community:

- First, **there's the ones who will migrate from M1 to M2.** The migration process will get smoother over time as more and more people will do it and understand the indepth mechanism of it.
- Second, **there's the ones who will not migrate to M2 anytime soon but will use the money they saved by not doing the migration to hire a part/full time security consultant to ensure their M1 store stays safe.**
- Finally, **there's the ones who will not do anything for several reasons**: first reason being "they're not aware of M1 EOL and haven't done patches/upgrades ever" (and the fact that people are not educated enough is probably the biggest problem in IT security). Another reason is that they can't afford either the migration or the security consultant.

> From similar experiences on other platforms did the community/hosting
>   companies keep focus on the old version and continued to offer
>   security fixes?

**There is already one unofficial repository which is community driven and which goal is to be the Magento 1 LTS** you can find it here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

I haven't heard about similar experiences on other platforms simply because **Magento 2 is way more than a V2 of Magento 1. It's a different software even though it originally was a port of M1.**

Regarding hosting companies, **I highly doubt they will stop supporting Magento 1 anytime soon after EOL**. As a comparison, I'm pretty sure a lot of hosting companies still run PHP 5.5 even though EOL was a few months ago.

Answer (score 2):

Magento announcement:

Magento Open Source 1 software security patches thru June 2020

Magento Open Source versions 1.5 to 1.9 will receive software security maintenance until June 2020.

https://info2.magento.com/M1OpenSource.html

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/supporting-magento-1-through-june-2020

Answer (score 1):

ONGOING MAGENTO 1 SUPPORT

Magento has announced, that "Magento 1 has been and will continue to be supported for the foreseeable future".

The formerly announced date (November 2018) is no longer an issue.

The "End of Life" of Magento 1.x is deferred at some indefinite future date with a "minimum 18-month notice before we make any changes to our support levels".

https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support

https://www.meet-magento.com/news/breaking-end-of-magento-1.x-support-extended